# mt19937 can't set random_device

Tags: c++, multithreading, random, mt19937

My code is failing as to not recognize "generator", but I declare it at the top of my C++ file. I need it to be thread-safe, so I declared it with "thread_local":

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

using namespace std;
thread_local mt19937 generator;

DWORD GenerateRandomNumber(DWORD dwMin, DWORD dwMax)
{
uniform_int_distribution <DWORD> distribution(dwMin, dwMax);
return distribution(generator);
}

int main() 
{
random_device rd;
generator(rd());
}
```

Comment: seed to be set in the constructor

Comment: How do I do that?

Answer (score -3):

[`mt19937::operator()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/mersenne_twister_engine/operator()) takes no parameters.

Comment: But I need to seed it. The MS example on <random> shows how to do it.

Comment: Well, it has a method named - wait for it - `seed()`

Comment: Asking for help in how to code this mt19937 so it's thread-safe and just gettting smart-alek answer. And a -1 because someone doesn't like the question asked?

Comment: There are no threads in the code shown. And the question didn't mention seeding - just asked why the code shown didn't compile, which I answered. In any case, I'm not sure I understand the nature of the difficulty. Now that you know how to seed the generator, just do that at the start of every thread that is going to use it.